# What's the differential of a couple

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, differential-topology, partial-derivative, differential-forms

Suppose we have a function $f : \Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^2$ such that $f:(x,y,z)\to(x+y^2,xy^2z) $

What's the differential of $f$?

**The result of my attempt :**
$D_f(x,y,z)(h,k,l)=(h+2yk,y^2zh+2xyzk+xy^2l)$

What I did was simply calculating the partial derivative of each function ( $f_1=x+y^2$ and $f_2=xy^2z$ ) but I'm not sure if that's the right way to go ( as in writing the result in a couple like I did).
Is the reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. In general the default format is column vectors, so that
$$
f([x,y,z]^T)=\pmatrix{x+y^2\\xy^2z}
$$
and
$$
J_f([x,y,z]^T)\pmatrix{h\\k\\l}=\pmatrix{h+2yk\\y^2zh+2xyzk+xy^2l}
=\pmatrix{1&2y&0\\y^2z&2xyz&xy^2}\pmatrix{h\\k\\l}
$$